# Laravel 8 Seeder Factory : Call to a member function count() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, factories

When I start seeding my database with `db:seed`, I got this error:

```
  Call to a member function count() on null

  at P:\<folderName>\<folderName>\src\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory.php:18
     14▕     {
     15▕         $factory = static::newFactory() ?: Factory::factoryForModel(get_called_class());
     16▕
     17▕         return $factory
  ➜  18▕                     ->count(is_numeric($parameters[0] ?? null) ? $parameters[0] : null)
     19▕                     ->state(is_array($parameters[0] ?? null) ? $parameters[0] : ($parameters[1] ?? []));
     20▕     }
     21▕
     22▕     /**

  1   P:\<folderName>\<folderName>\src\database\seeders\UserSeeder.php:23
      App\Models\UserPhoto::factory()

  2   P:\<folderName>\<folderName>\src\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Database\Seeders\UserSeeder::run()
```

I tried to override the default factory, following the example in the  [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#connecting-factories-and-models), but it did not help.

**Here's my model:**

```
class UserPhoto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Create a new factory instance for the model.
     */
    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return UserPhotoFactory::new();
    }

}
```

If I delete `->has(UserPhoto::factory(1))` Users table seeds normally

**Seeder:**

```
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $city = City::first();
        User::factory(15)
            ->for($city)
            ->has(UserPhoto::factory(1))
            ->create()
        ;

//        UserPhoto::factory();
    }
}
```

**Factory:**

```
class UserPhotoFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = UserPhoto::class;

    public function configure()
    {
        $this->afterCreating(function (UserPhoto $photo) {
            $height = $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 900);
            $width = $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 900);
            $contents = file_get_contents('www.placecage.com/c/'.$height.'/'.$width);
            $path = 'users/images/'.$photo->user_id.'/'.$photo->id.'.jpg';
            Storage::disk('local')->put($path, $contents);
        });
    }

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
//            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ];
    }
}
```

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    public function city() {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }

    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserPhoto::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be honest, this code is a mess. You need to read the documentation on factories. You don't need a factory method on the model, for instance. Also, some of the definitions should be moved from `configure` to `definition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configure method needs to return `$this`

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php#L171

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the relationship name of UserPhoto in `City` Model, I assume you are using `userPhoto` so I passed it as 2nd arg in `has(UserPhoto::factory(), 'userPhoto')`

```
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $city = City::first();
        User::factory(15)
            ->for($city)
            ->has(UserPhoto::factory(1), 'userPhoto')
            ->create()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you talking about `City` Model? `UserPhoto` is related to `User`. 
So, I tried to pass the relationship name `'photos'` as 2nd arg, but it did not help.
I also added a `User` Model in my question.